# Probability Of a 4 sided die

Tags: probability

A fair $4$-sided die is rolled twice and we assume that all sixteen
possible outcomes are equally likely. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the result of the $1^{\large\text{st}}$ and the
$2^{\large\text{nd}}$ roll, respectively. We wish to determine the conditional probability $P(A|B)$
where
$A = \max(X,Y)=m$
and
$B= \min(X,Y)=2,\quad m\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Can somebody first explain me this question and then explain its answer. I'm having trouble in approaching it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially there are 16 equally likely possibilities for the two dice rolls:

```
            First
       1    2    3    4

S  1   X    X    X    X
e
c  2   X    X    X    X
o
n  3   X    X    X    X
d
   4   X    X    X    X
```

If the minimum roll is $2$ then there are 5 equally likely possibilities for the two dice rolls:

```
            First
       1    2    3    4

S  1        
e
c  2        X    X    X
o
n  3        X        
d
   4        X
```

So for the conditional probability of the maximum

- $P(A=1|B=2)=0$,
- $P(A=2|B=2)=\frac{1}{5}$,
- $P(A=3|B=2)=\frac{2}{5}$,
- $P(A=4|B=2)=\frac{2}{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Initially you have 16 possible outcomes.

A: (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) ... (4,3) (4,4)

Q: Assume that B is true. (How many outcomes are there left?)

A: min(X,Y)=2. So 5 outcomes left: (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (3,2) (4,2)

Q: What values can m take?

A: m is the max of two numbers up to 4. So m can take values 1,2,3,4

Q: How many possible outcomes for each value of m?

A: Taking the 3 outcomes left: max(2,2)=2. max(2,3)=max(3,2)=3. max(2,4)=max(4,2)=4

```
m=1: P(A|B)=0/5
m=2: P(A|B)=1/5
m=3: P(A|B)=2/5
m=4: P(A|B)=2/5
```

Comment: Then 1,3,4 are left?

Comment: each outcome is a combination of 2 numbers (i.e. 2 rolls). (1,4) is a possible outcome. but it's not fulfilling B, as min(1,4)=1. Not 2. So how many pairs (X,Y) can you form with min(X,Y)=2

Comment: I can form (2,3), (2,4)..? I'm sorry if I'm wrong, question is quite confusing for me